# Scope and responsibilities change after starting at a new job

Tags: professionalism, management, career-development

I started a new jobs a few months ago. I signed up to run a business group at the company which has three departments.

Two months after I joined, the company wanted to spin off my business group as a new venture and grow my group 2x-3x in a year.

They later hired a manager to focus on growing the team and I will report to this new manager. My scope will shifted to one department in the group and cross department collaboration.

This is frustrating to me since I have just started everything and things get to change mid-way. Also, the nature of work requires cross department work to get business results.

I feel like one step back in my career since I get to work on a smaller scope.

How should I deal with this situation?

Answer (score 4):

> How should I deal with this situation?

Decide if you want this role reporting to the new manager or not.

If not, ask for a different role or find a new job in a new company.

Comment: there is an option c: ask for a career path that is suiting. A temporary step back can be the step to the role you want, if it is agreed beforehand. Decide if you trust your company to follow through.

Comment: If you ask for a new role, you might be told, "there isn't one".  So you will have to decide if the company is a correct fit for you. Jobs change over time, responsibilities in a job, are determine by the company not the employee.

Comment: @Donald I am in the same situation right now, it’s all fair in saying that but what if your responsibilities change to the point that the role becomes unsuitable